# Geometric interpretation of direction cosines

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, normed-spaces

I have a task to: From the definition of the direction cosines, it is easy to see that the sum of the squares of the direction cosines is 1. For the special case of $\mathbb R^3$, draw a sketch and use properties of right triangles to show this geometrically.

Clearly, this can be verified algebraically with $\theta_i$ the angle that x makes with the unit vectors:

$$\begin{split}\cos(\theta_i)&= \frac{\langle x, e_i\rangle}{\|x\|\|e_i\|}=\frac 1 {\|x\|}x_i\end{split}$$

So algebraically, we have $\sum\cos^2(\theta_i)=\frac{\sum x_i^2}{\|x\|^2}=1$, as claimed.

I had more trouble with coming up with the geometric verification in $\mathbb R^2$, let alone $\mathbb R^3$. I got the hypotenuse was equal to the inverse of the direction cosine, and they overlap, not forming a right triangle. How does one show this in $\mathbb R^2$ for the vector shown?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the following illustration:
[image: Illustration cosines]
It should be clear that:
$$x_1^2 + x_2^2 = |x|^2\cos^2(\theta_1) + |x|^2\cos^2(\theta_2) \iff \cos^2(\theta_1) + \cos^2(\theta_2) = \frac{x_1^2 + x_2^2}{|x|^2} = 1$$
Or intuitively. $\left(\cos(\theta_1), \cos(\theta_2)\right) = (x_1/|x|, x_2/|x|)$ are points on the unit circle, since $\cos(\theta_2) = \sin(\theta_1)$ and thus we're dealing with the point $(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ which is of course on the unit circle and thus has unit length.

The generalization to 3D should be clear from here?

> Add the coordinate $x_3 = |x|\cos(\theta_3)$ or intuitively - we're dealing with the unit sphere.

Hope this answer your question, if anything is still unclear feel free to ask.

Comment: Nice, yeah scaling by the length keeps it in the same direction, laying it on the unit circle/sphere/etc.